# I can't upgrade!

Tags: apt, update

I was installing and removing packages recently and i noticed that it said: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.` as soon as i ran the command. But, when i ran `sudo apt-get update` it still said: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.` When i ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` however it also said:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi0
lxpanel lxpanel-data nuscratch raspberrypi-bootloader
```

How may i update these packages?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question or the one I'm about to recommend you ask yourself first: "What does it mean when `apt-get` says 'packages have been kept back'?".  Someone somewhere knows, and I bet they and/or someone else have explained it already, on the internet (but again, none of them include me).  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade will usually handle the issue of held back packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those packages were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and no longer needed.

`apt-get upgrade` only upgrade all your current packages to newest version.

`apt-get dist-upgrade` in addition to performing the function of `upgrade`, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages and remove redundant ones. So you should use this command unless you have specific need for those packages to be kept :)

Comment: But i thought if you had packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are no longer needed `apt-get autoremove` removed them.

Comment: so have you ran the `autoremove` command yet? those packages suppose to be uninstalled after an autoremove too.